# Google Chrome installs without consent

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

Last night I shut down my computer for the first time in ages because the fans were going CRAZY (I normally restart it). When I turned it on in the morning, I found this:

[chrome in start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGipU.png)

I have **no** memory of it being installed.

My computer is an old HP ProBook running Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Would you mind adding a question to your statements?

Comment: Are you trying to find out why or are you trying to uninstall it? Did it get installed along with any other programs you installed recently? Only you know what else has happened on your computer to give us an idea of whether that is a possibility.

Comment: Chrome is not installed without user intervention.  So it sounds like you simply forgot, thankfully, it's extremely easy to uninstall

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Chrome was installed together with another application.
You could track down when it was installed and see if you remember installing any other applications or compare it with the date and time of other applications on your computer.

To check this:

1. Open the Windows Settings (press *Windows + i* on your keyboard)
2. Navigate to the *Apps* category
3. On the left column select *Apps & features*
4. On the right all the installed applications on your computer will be listed.
5. Search for Google Chrome and click on its name
6. You will see the installation date below its size

If you want, you can directly uninstall Google Chrome from there by clicking *Uninstall* after selecting Google Chrome.